# multiple answers to a question

Tags: discussion

Many a times you ask a question and get the answer in parts but not "**a perfect answer**". I mean, say 2 people answered the question but partly. Together, these answers form a complete answer.Both answers helped me. I am not saying, the answers are overlapping. Which answer should I mark as actual answer. It will be unjust to mark one answer as complete and ignore another. Would having a system of allowing to mark multiple answers advantageous?

Comment: You can upvote more than one answer. It's only the acceptance (check mark) where you have to pick the *most* useful one.

Comment: @RetoKoradi : Thats the thing. Both the answers are part of a complete answer. Both deserve a check mark

Comment: Yes, but at least you can recognize all useful answers with an upvote. So I wouldn't say that you ignore them. For the acceptance, if the question/answers are very recent, you can also wait for a bit. Maybe one of the posters will make their answer more complete. Or more answers that are even better will be posted.

Comment: I would upvote both the answers but choosing one over the other would be tricky. After waiting a couple of days for better answers as @RetoKoradi suggests, you could post your own answer that combines the two to provide a more complete solution for future visitors. If you are still unsure, you can _accept_ your own answer. _Technically_, it would be the real complete solution.